# Global Mouse Hook: Modify mouse position before input hits hooked application

Tags: c++, winapi, hook, mouse

I created a global mouse hook where I tried to change the x and y cursor position that the hooked application receives without actually moving the cursor.  For some reason it did not work.  So I tried to change the cursor position to see if it would change anything.  But that didn't work either; the input reached the window before the cursor moved. Below is my code.

```
 LRESULT CALLBACK procMouseMsg(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam){
    //this is the hook procedure

    if (wParam == WM_LBUTTONDOWN){
        // Tactic #1 -problem: Nothing seems to happen...?
        ((PMSLLHOOKSTRUCT)lParam)->pt.x = 389; // 
        ((PMSLLHOOKSTRUCT)lParam)->pt.y = 15;

        // Tactic #2 -problem: cursor moves after input hits hooked application
        SetPhysicalCursorPos(389, 15);  

        // Tactics were not used at the same time.
    }
    return CallNextHookEx(hkKey, nCode, wParam, lParam);

}


 void __stdcall SetHook()
{
    if (hkMouse == NULL){
        hkMouse = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_MOUSE_LL, procMouseMsg, hInstHookDll, 0);
    }
}
```

Am I missing something big here?  Maybe I should just kill the input in **CallNextHookEx** and *then* move the cursor, manually send an input and then move the cursor back?  I feel like this should be easier.

BTW I'm not writing a keylogger or anything sketchy.  I'm trying to do an operating system overlay.  It seems like people assume the worst.

Comment: Not all hooks allow you to modify input, I guess `WM_MOUSE_LL` is one that doesn't.

Comment: That is actually a bit saddening to hear.  Off the top of your head do you know if there are any hooks that do and also relate to this problem?

Comment: You cannot *"kill"* or otherwise modify input in a low-level mouse hook. What is it you are really trying to do? *"Operating system overlay"* isn't telling a whole lot.

Comment: That's not true.  I would just return -1 instead of returning CallNextHookEx.  What I'm trying to do is show a window in one place on the overlay while it's actually in another place on the desktop.  The mouse input still needs to work when the mouse coordinates are not where the thing they're clicking on actually is.

Comment: Probably the same problem faced in the following post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14439491/how-can-i-set-cursor-position-from-mouse-hook-in-windows.

That post has a workaround as well.

Comment: Thank you for this but I just learned how to write a driver and now intercept the input before it hits userland.